# Libvirt pool cannot see or create rbd clones

Tags: libvirt, ceph

While trying to get a cloned disk running from my OS snapshot I run into the problem that Libvirt cannot see existing images cloned from a snapshot. Created via:

```sh
$ rbd -p vmdisks clone vmdisks/coreos_2023@base vmdisks/coreos00.disk
```

The base image has the one snapshot 'base' and is protected. The cloned disk is created just fine:

```sh
$ rbd -p vmdisks info coreos00.disk
rbd image 'coreos00.disk':
        size 8.49GiB in 2174 objects
        order 22 (4MiB objects)
        block_name_prefix: rbd_data.48a99c6b8b4567
        format: 2
        features: layering
        flags: 
        create_timestamp: Thu Apr 25 14:46:52 2019
        parent: vmdisks/coreos_2023@base
        overlap: 8.49GiB
```

I temporarily have Libvirt configured with a rbd pool that uses the ceph admin user. But I cannot see the cloned disk. Just the parent:

```sh
virsh # vol-list --pool rbd_image_root
 Name                 Path                                    
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 coreos_2023 vmdisks/coreos_2023
```

If I try to create the cloned image from within virsh I run into the following issue:

```
virsh # vol-clone --pool rbd_image_root coreos_2023 coreos00.disk
error: Failed to clone vol from coreos_2023
error: failed to iterate RBD snapshot coreos_2023@base: Operation not permitted
```

Note that this pool uses the Ceph admin user which makes the Operation not permitted a tad odd.

Am I missing a configuration option here that would allow for the pool to use clones? I can't find any information on this in the documentation so far. And the source code of libvirt looks like it should support both features.

Versions:

```
Libvirt Machine: Ubuntu 18.04
Compiled against library: libvirt 4.0.0
Using library: libvirt 4.0.0
Using API: QEMU 4.0.0
Running hypervisor: QEMU 2.11.1

Ceph Machine: openSUSE Leap 42.3
Ceph 12.2.5
```

#### Update

When I create a volume like this:

```xml
<volume>
   <name>coreos00.disk</name>
   <capacity unit="bytes">9116319744</capacity>
   <target>
       <format type="raw"></format>
       <permissions>
           <mode>644</mode>
       </permissions>
   </target>
   <backingStore>
       <path>vmdisks/coreos_2023</path>
       <format type="raw"></format>
   </backingStore>
</volume>
```

Which does not seem to work with the backing store either as it creates
an empty volume without the underlying parent. But when I now delete
the volume via rbd and create a new clone it shows up in libvirt and
can be used by the machine.

```sh
$ rbd -p vmdisks rm coreos00.disk
$ rbd clone vmdisks/coreos_2023@basis vmdisks/coreos00.disk
```

Sadly this is not a very efficient way to create the clones I would
say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a bug with libvirt in the end. A simple fix provided by [Michal Privoznik](https://www.redhat.com/archives/libvirt-users/2019-April/msg00065.html)  solves the problem.

```
diff --git i/src/storage/storage_backend_rbd.c w/src/storage/storage_backend_rbd.c
index f8c968e682..08f8123678 100644
--- i/src/storage/storage_backend_rbd.c
+++ w/src/storage/storage_backend_rbd.c
@@ -1038,7 +1038,7 @@ virStorageBackendRBDIterateCb(uint64_t offset ATTRIBUTE_UNUSED,
      * searching any further.
      */
     *(int*) arg = 1;
-    return -1;
+    return 0;
 }

 static int
```

**Update**

The [official patch was updated](https://www.redhat.com/archives/libvir-list/2019-April/msg01483.html) and should be included in libvirt 5.3.0